# Best Machine learning algorithm to detect fire in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I need to code a fire detector using OpenCV and Ive been googling for days on what to use but failed. Everything I find in google is all about haar detecting rigid objects especially face
What is the best ML to detect fire? I have to use a ML algorithm, that means no Haar or Viola algorithms.

Any suggestions for this? and if possible can explain why that certain algorithm is applicable in detecting fire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better if you consider it as machine vision problem rather than computer vision problem. Instead of using RGB camera, its better to go for RGB-IR camera.

Infrared cameras are sensitive to heat content in scene. When you use IR camerasm with simple algorithms or mere thresholding you can detect fire in scene in case of dark environment.

Cheap RGB-IR cameras are available online like Raspberry Pi's Pi-Noir camera or you can convert your camera to RGB-IR camera by removing IR protection film.

Comment: I already have thought about IR camera before.. But I really need to program a ML algorithm for it

Comment: ML algorithm depends on how image acquisition is, its advised to capture images and then try using suitable algorithm

Comment: So you mean do trial and error with different algorithms?

Comment: No, different methods work on different situations. To understand what kind of pre-processing steps are to be used, what kind of feature detection methods are to be used, its better to have image first and then decide upon

Comment: What are the factors in the images that can influence the decision in choosing the method?